# Dialogflow information/analytics retrieval and feed back to user

Tags: dialogflow-es, analytics

I am just starting to use dialogflow. 
I am wondering if I can retrieve information back to the user (analytics)?

Say a user asks the chatbot "how long have I spent time with you?" or after a few quizzes, the user asks "what is my score"?
The chatbot is being able to tell the user regarding the information.

If so, is it able to do it via the console or needs to code in local?

Thanks

Comment: I have been trying something similar too. It is totally possible to achieve what you are asking. it involves both console and code. here's a blog I have been referring to: https://miningbusinessdata.com/api-ai-tutorial-passing-data-from-browser-localstorage-to-webhooks/

Comment: You can use Firebase Database or storage available in Google assistant for that purpose